# Salesforce Apex Http Request - REST + OAUTH 1.0

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex

I'm trying to communicate with an REST API via Salesforce.
I have a postman collection that works just fine, but when trying to replicate it using apex I get a Status 400 (Bad Request) Error.

The URL is already registered in the Remote Site Settings.
Here's my code (I'm not allowed to post the parameters but believe me they are the same as the postman collection):

```
public static void testCode(){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('<API URL>?script=1022&deploy=1');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    String nonce     = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomLong());
    String timestamp = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime() / 1000);
    String consumerSecret = '<SECRET>';

    String header = 'OAuth ';
    header+= 'realm="8305111_SB1", ';
    header+= 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"';
    header+= 'oauth_consumer_key="<KEY>", ';
    header+= 'oauth_token="<TOKEN>", ';
    header+= 'oauth_token_secret="<TOKEN>", ';
    header+= 'oauth_version="1.0", ';
    header+= 'oauth_timestamp="'+timestamp+'", ';

    header+= 'oauth_nonce="'+nonce+'", ';
    Map<String,String> parameters = new Map<String,String>();
    parameters.put('realm','8305111_SB1');
    parameters.put('oauth_signature_method','HMAC-SHA1');
    parameters.put('oauth_consumer_key','<KEY>');
    parameters.put('oauth_token','<TOKEN>');
    parameters.put('oauth_token_secret','<SECRET>');
    parameters.put('oauth_version','1.0');
    parameters.put('oauth_timestamp',timestamp);
    parameters.put('oauth_nonce',nonce);
    header += 'oauth_signature="'+generateSignature(request, consumerSecret, parameters)+'"';


    request.setHeader('Authorization', header);

    request.setBody('{"Mundo": "Mundo"}');
    System.Debug('AUTH HEADER:');
    for(String s : header.Split(',')){System.Debug(s);}
    System.Debug('BODY: '+request.getBody());
    System.debug('REQUEST  --> '+request);
    System.debug('RESPONSE --> '+http.send(request));
}

private static String generateSignature(HttpRequest req, String consumerSecret, Map<String,String> parameters) {
    String s = createBaseString(parameters,req);
    Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac( 'HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(s), Blob.valueOf(consumerSecret) );
    return EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');
}

private static String createBaseString(Map<String,String> oauthParams, HttpRequest req) {
    Map<String,String> p = oauthParams.clone();
    if(req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase('post') && req.getBody()!=null &&
        req.getHeader('Content-Type')=='application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
        p.putAll(getUrlParams(req.getBody()));
    }
    String host = req.getEndpoint();
    Integer n = host.indexOf('?');
    if(n>-1) {
        p.putAll(getUrlParams(host.substring(n+1)));
        host = host.substring(0,n);
    }
    List<String> keys = new List<String>();
    keys.addAll(p.keySet());
    keys.sort();
    String s = keys.get(0)+'='+p.get(keys.get(0));
    for(Integer i=1;i<keys.size();i++) {
        s = s + '&' + keys.get(i)+'='+p.get(keys.get(i));
    }

    // According to OAuth spec, host string should be lowercased, but Google and LinkedIn
    // both expect that case is preserved.
    return req.getMethod().toUpperCase()+ '&' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(host, 'UTF-8') + '&' + 
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(s, 'UTF-8');
}

private static Map<String,String> getUrlParams(String value) {

    Map<String,String> res = new Map<String,String>();
    if(value==null || value=='') {
        return res;
    }
    for(String s : value.split('&')) {
        System.debug('getUrlParams: '+s);
        List<String> kv = s.split('=');
        if(kv.size()>1) {
            // RFC 5849 section 3.4.1.3.1 and 3.4.1.3.2 specify that parameter names
            // and values are decoded then encoded before being sorted and concatenated
            // Section 3.6 specifies that space must be encoded as %20 and not +
            String encName = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(kv[0], 
                             'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8').replace('+','%20');
            String encValue = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(kv[1], 'UTF-8'), 
            'UTF-8').replace('+','%20');
            //System.debug('getUrlParams:  -> '+encName+','+encValue);
            res.put(encName,encValue);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a public API you'll have hard time, internet strangers can't replicate what you're doing ;) consider sending these request to some service like requestbin, httpbin etc (or maybe you have your own web server you can use just to log the request... I think some of them are paid, keep googling). Compare what comes out of apex with what postman sends?

Assuming they really are identical - could be some IP whitelisting the vendor is doing? Maybe they need to whitelist Salesforce IP addresses (or maybe they banned AWS and you're on a hyperforce org)

Does the vendor provide code samples for Java or C#? They should be relatively easy to rewrite to apex...
When all else fails you may have to create a proxy service. SF contacts your server for data, you repackage/forward/whatever the request, send results back to SF